# check button with action onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form contain a list of question and one of the questions is a check button have a yes and no value and we want if the user selects yes will display another question is hide with a text box? using javascript

this is my code

```
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <img alt="" src="images/factor.jpg">
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-md-9 editContent"><h5 style= "font-size: 18px ;font-weight: bold ">Is journal has an impact factor or not?</h5>

                      <p><input type="radio" name="impact" value="1"/>Yes<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="impact" value="0" required/>No</p>
                      </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.col -->

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <img alt="" src="images/factor.jpg">
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                       <div class="col-md-9 editContent"><h5 style= "font-size: 18px ;font-weight: bold ">Determine the impact factor of journal if there is one:</h5>

                        <p><input type="number"  min="0" max="3"  value="0.000" step="0.001"
                            name="factornumber" required/></p>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
      </div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Javascript is not Java. Don't use incorrect/inappropriate tags.

Comment: Write your code and if you can't get it to work we will help you. Show us your work.

Answer (score 0):

in this block :

```
<div class="col-md-9 editContent"><h5 style= "font-size: 18px ;font-weight: bold ">Is journal has an impact factor or not?</h5>

                      <p><input type="radio" name="impact" value="1" class="yes"/>Yes<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="impact" value="0" required/>No</p>
                      </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
```

you had to add the checked attribute to one of the two inputs let's add it on No so it will be by default a No in the answer , like this

```
<input type="radio" name="impact" value="0" checked />No</p>
```

and in your HTML code add an id to the second question name for example "seconQuest",and in your JS code it will be similar to this

```
    var answer;
    $("input.yes").is(":checked") ? answer = 'YES' : answer = 'no';
    if(answer === 'YES'){
      $("div#secondQuest").show();
    }
```

NB : the sencond div will be similar to this :

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="secondQuest">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
```

hope it helpd

Comment: the another question is hidden and when select yes it will appear?

Comment: it does not work.
if the second div like this:
 <div class="col-md-6"  id="secondQuest"  hidden="true">
                      <div class="row">


are the code you write it will work?

Comment: in the CSS you have to put a style to that div by setting 
div#secondQuest{display:none}

Comment: @user6276085 you can upvote my answer if it helps and set it as the answer , Thanks